# How can I change my iCloud account on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud

My wife had to get a new iPhone and they put my iCloud account on her phone.  I am trying to change it but when i go into Settings > iCloud, the email address is grayed out so I can't see how to change it.

How can I change the iCloud account on my wife's phone so she gets her contacts, etc and not mine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under **Settings / iCloud** you'll see a big red button labeled as **Delete Account**. Contrary to what it appears, it won't actually *delete* the account, nor your Apple ID, it will only delete the iCloud's content from your device.

So, to change the device's iCloud account just delete the current one and then log in appropriately.

Comment: But it says it will delete everything in the iCloud and I am scared of losing all my photos & video

Comment: It wont delete the contents of the cloud, if both you devices have the Photostream you can see that once you remove the iCloud account you photos will still be there.